# Editing has_one objects with form_for in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, form-for, has-one

I have a has_one / belongs_to association between two models -> User and ContactCard. While I am able to create a contact card for a user, whenever I try to edit the card the create action is called from the ContactCardsController rather than update (I can tell because I have different success messages on each).  It changes the attributes of the contact card just fine I have to say.  I'm mostly happy it's working but would rather patch up any gaps in my understanding of rails paths and associations.  What am I missing? Why isn't it using the action I expect? Also if you know of any relevant examples on the web or on github I could study up on, I'm all ears.  Thanks!

Contact Cards Controller...

```
class ContactCardsController < ApplicationController      


 def create 
   current_user.build_contact_card(params[:contact_card]) 
   if current_user.contact_card.save
     flash[:success] = "Contact Card created!"
     redirect_to '/account'
   else
     flash[:error] = "Fail!"
     redirect_to '/account'
  end
 end  

  def update
    if current_user.contact_card.update_attributes(params[:contact_card])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated."
      redirect_to '/account'
    else
      flash[:error] = "Fail!"
      redirect_to '/account'
    end
  end
```

Link to edit form...

```
<%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_contact_card_path(current_user) %>
```

Edit form...

```
<%= form_for [current_user, current_user.build_contact_card], :url => user_contact_card_path(current_user) do |f| %>

<%= f.label :first_name %>
<%= f.text_field :first_name %>    

<%= f.label :last_name %> 
<%= f.text_field :last_name %>

<%= f.submit "Save Contact Details", :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>

<% end %>
```

Relevant Routes...

```
resources :users do      
  resource :contact_card    
   .....
```

The User model has_one :contact_card and the ContactCard model belongs_to:user

Comment: try edit_user_contact_card_path(current_user.id), not sure because I don't know which authentication scheme you use.  Also look at the ContactCard table, I'd bet you have a record for each card you've 'edited'

Comment: I tried that and it still goes through the create path for some reason.  current_user returns the user object for the current user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<%= form_for [current_user, current_user.build_contact_card], :url =>   user_contact_card_path(current_user) do |f| %>
```

This is building a new contact card every time you edit!  Change it to

```
<%= form_for [current_user,contact_card], :url => user_contact_card_path(current_user) do |f| %>
```

You'd want the build_contact_card in the create action of User controller probably

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I missed that.